# Combining C# with JavaScript for interface extension

Tags: c#

The background is that Microsoft NAV 2013 R2 Allows you to create add-ins for this software with C# or JavaScript. C# should work in windows only client and the javascript add-in should work in both environments.

The reality is that javascript is styled badly in the windows client, because windows client is written with native code and uses some sort of element positioning code written in that native code. THe javascript add-in is loaded inside IE, which is embedded into that native windows window. So what the native code does - layouts and styles only the IE frame but not whats inside - that up to individual developer.

I though that it should be possible to implement the add-in C# interface in both - c# and javascript and somehow load javascript only code when the user is using browser, but thats for another day.

For now I'd like to ask you (as I have little to no experience in C#) How to implement interface in C# ?

I've used these samples as examples:
[For the Javascript add-in](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn182584(v=nav.71).aspx) and
[For the C# add-in](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/nav/archive/2012/11/01/source-code-released-for-lync-communication-add-in-for-microsoft-dynamics-nav-2013.aspx)

This is code that I've written:

```
namespace HelloWorld
{
    [ControlAddInExport("Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Client.HelloWorld")]
    public interface HelloWorld : IControlAddIn
    {
        [ApplicationVisible]
        event MethodInvoker AddInReady;

        [ApplicationVisible]
        event MethodInvoker onPush;

        [ApplicationVisible]
        void setButtonImage(string dataUri);

        [ApplicationVisible]
        void setLabel(string label);

        bool AllowCaptionControl();
    }

    [ControlAddInExport("Microsoft.Dynamics.Nav.Client.Helloworld")]
    public class HelloWorldClass : HelloWorld
    {
        private UserControl1 myUserControl;
        private ElementHost presenceHost;
        public override bool AllowCaptionControl
        {
            get
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        protected override Control CreateControl()
        {
            this.myUserControl = new UserControl1();
            this.presenceHost = new ElementHost
            {
                Child = this.myUserControl,
                AutoSize = true,
            };
            this.presenceHost.EnabledChanged += delegate { this.myUserControl.CanEnable = this.presenceHost.Enabled; };
            this.presenceHost.ParentChanged += delegate
            {
                if (HelloWorld.AddInReady != null)
                {
                    HelloWorld.AddInReady();
                }
            };
            return this.presenceHost;
        }

    }
}
```

The visual studio compiler throws me this:

```
Error   1   'HelloWorld.HelloWorldClass' does not implement interface member 'Microsoft.Dynamics.Framework.UI.Extensibility.IControlAddIn.Initialize(Microsoft.Dynamics.Framework.UI.Extensibility.IControlAddInSite)'
Error   2   'HelloWorld.HelloWorldClass' does not implement interface member 'HelloWorld.HelloWorld.AllowCaptionControl()'
Error   3   'HelloWorld.HelloWorldClass' does not implement interface member 'HelloWorld.HelloWorld.setLabel(string)'
Error   4   'HelloWorld.HelloWorldClass' does not implement interface member 'HelloWorld.HelloWorld.setButtonImage(string)'
Error   5   'HelloWorld.HelloWorldClass' does not implement interface member 'HelloWorld.HelloWorld.onPush'
Error   6   'HelloWorld.HelloWorldClass' does not implement interface member 'HelloWorld.HelloWorld.AddInReady'
Error   7   'HelloWorld.HelloWorldClass.AllowCaptionControl': no suitable method found to override
Error   8   'HelloWorld.HelloWorldClass.CreateControl()': no suitable method found to override
Error   9   The event 'HelloWorld.HelloWorld.AddInReady' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -= (except when used from within the type 'HelloWorld.HelloWorld')
Error   10  The event 'HelloWorld.HelloWorld.AddInReady' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -= (except when used from within the type 'HelloWorld.HelloWorld')
```

Is it what I'm doing (trying to implement HelloWorld interface with a class) is stupid, impossible or what?

How to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Click on **HelloWorld**

```
public class HelloWorldClass : HelloWorld
```

Hover over the little blue bar that appears under "*HelloWorld*".

Click the down arrow and chose either *explicit* or *standard* implementation.